# Can you deal damage to two targets each round, using Twinned Spell and Witch Bolt?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, metamagic

A small follow-up to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47327/are-there-ways-to-concentrate-on-more-than-one-spell-at-a-time/47401#47401): if you cast Witch Bolt + Twinned Spell, when you use your action to deal WB damage on your next turn, do you deal damage to both targets or to one? I lean towards the latter, following the answer above (that it's one spell with two effects/targets), but wanted to check.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're targeting a second creature with the *same* spell. I think that for all intents and purposes *all* of the effects, even the use your action to damage them effect from Witch Bolt should continue.

[This](http://community.wizards.com/forum/rules-questions/threads/4124331) thread from the WOTC forums seems to agree with this interpretation. Particularly [this](http://community.wizards.com/comment/51048786#comment-51048786) post by Plaguescarred.

If twinned spell is going to be possible it basically turns the target line of Witch Bolt into "you target 2 creatures" and then the action on following turns would damage *both* creatures.

[Mike Mearls confirms](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/506908500392280064) this on twitter ([HT CTWind](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47475/can-you-deal-damage-to-two-targets-each-round-using-twinned-spell-and-witch-bol/47476#comment94399_47476))

> One spell instance, two targets.