# Does the Tempest domain's Destructive Wrath maximize ongoing damage from a twinned Witch Bolt?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, cleric, metamagic

I have a multiclass tempest cleric/sorcerer.

If I twin Witch Bolt and then use *Channel Divinity: Destructive Wrath,* which allows me to deal max thunder or lightning damage, are both bolts impacted? I assume I can concentrate on both because it is one spell casting but is the lingering effect of witch bolt also maximized?

Comment: Related: [Can you deal damage to two targets each round, using Twinned Spell and Witch Bolt?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47475)

Answer (score 12):

You can do this, but you will need to expend multiple uses of Channel Divinity.

Channel Divinity: Destructive Wrath (PHB, P. 62; emphases mine)

> **When you roll** lightning or thunder damage, **you can use your Channel Divinity** to deal maximum damage, instead of rolling.

Note that this use of Channel Divinity is for a damage **roll**, not for a spell. It can be for any effect that causes lightning or thunder damage.

If you expend a sorcery point to Twin Spell a Witch Bolt, you will have two spell attacks that could each do damage. Each is a separate damage roll, so each would require a separate use of Channel Divinity to maximize. The ongoing damage each round from Witch Bolt is another separate roll, and thus would require another use of Channel Divinity. Given that clerics have a maximum of three uses of Channel Divinity between rests (and that at 18th level), this is probably not that efficient.

Comment: This makes it more efficient to go straight storm sorcerer or bronze / blue dragon sorcerer, since they get plenty of damage bonuses. Although cleric may give enough defensive bonuses to make it worthwhile anyways.

Comment: This answer contradicts [this other answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/49012/32518). Which is right?

Comment: @galdre It's not clear, and there are no clear rulings. I would treat a multi-target Witch Bolt like an Eldritch Blast, rolling attacks and damage separately. In any case, each round of ongoing damage would also require a separate Channel Divinity use.

Comment: @MarkCogan - It seems pretty clear from the rules cited in the answer galdre linked states that you wouldn't need to use 2 channels to maximize the damage. Consider that you can maximize a lightning bolt, which can hit multiple targets, and you don't need to use 2 channels for that. This is no different. CD from Tempest maximizes the spell damage, twinning the spell just gives it a second target. It's not a separate spell, it's the same spell, so the maximization would apply.

Comment: My answer, and the rules it cites, doesn't mention targets. What matters is the damage rolls. You roll once for _lightning bolt_, regardless of the number of targets, so you would use one use of _Channel Divinity_. Twin Spell, in most cases, would require additional damage rolls.

Answer (score -5):

Yes it should do max damage.

Per PHB PG. 289
Witch bolt is lightening damage.

Per PBH PG. 62

> channel divinity: destructive wrath
>   when you roll lightening or thunder damage, you can use your channel divinity to deal
>   Maximum damage instead of rolling.

I do not see this being limited to cleric sourced lightening in any way.

Sorcerer twinned spells select another target, so that would generate another damage roll, so a twinned witch bolt spell would also be a perfect use of this feature. Very powerful.

Comment: Sorry - my question is less about whether I can apply the cleric ability to sorcerer spells and more if the cleric ability impacts both twinned spells and the twinned lingering effects.

Comment: @Zule I read the section on twinned spell's and I can't see anything limiting its use when coupled with channel divinity. I'd say this is a powerful combo. I have added that to my answer.