# Is there a class ability, spell or other, that lets you share spells with your familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars

Scenario:

I have a Wizard/Warlock with the Pact of the Chain feature, who I have themed off He-Man. I love the idea of using [Tenser's Transformation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tensers-transformation) to buff both he and his familiar up for combat.  However, it has a range of self, which seems to really limit my options.

Does anyone have a work around for this? I am willing to change my class or multiclass as needed. (We stick to using the hardcover books, and not UA or 3rd party stuff)

Comment: Sam, just an FYI, when you search for something on D&D Beyond, you can right-click the result you want to link to then "Copy Link Address". That way you can link directly to the spell, ability or rule instead of to the marketplace page even if you don't own a copy on D&D Beyond.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The closest suggestions to what you want that I have found are a Beast Master ranger or the *find [greater] steed* spells

I was unable to find anything that allows a wizard/warlock to have self-only spells also affect a familiar summoned via *[find familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar)*. The closest things I could find would require heavy multiclassing into undesired classes, and still wouldn't actually affect the familiar, but here's what I found...

---

The Beast Master ranger gets a class feature at 15th level called Share Spells (PHB, p. 93), which says:

> Beginning at 15th level, when you cast a spell targeting yourself, you can also affect your beast companion with the spell if the beast is within 30 feet of you.

This doesn't affect a familiar via *find familiar* like you wanted, but it does allow your beast companion to benefit from *Tenser's transformation*. Note that with 15 levels in ranger, you wouldn't have access to *Tenser's transformation* anyway.

---

Alternatively, if you were able to gain access to the *[find steed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-steed)* (PHB, p. 240) or *[find greater steed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-greater-steed)* (XGtE, p. 156) spells (which, as far as I'm aware, means taking levels in paladin or bard<sup>1</sup>), both of which say:

> While mounted on it, you can make any spell you cast that targets only you also target [your/the] mount.

Again, this still doesn't affect the familiar via *find familiar*, but this should also allow a summoned mount to be affected by *Tenser's transformation*. If you took the bard route, you could learn *Tenser's transformation* via Magical Secrets, otherwise this build *also* doesn't have access to *Tenser's transformation*.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Actually, there is another way for this to work; rather than being of a class that can cast either *find steed* or *find greater steed*, you can instead use the *Ring of Spell Storing*, which can hold spells of 5th level or lower. If you know a paladin or bard with either of the steed spells, they can cast it into the ring, allowing you, a wizard/warlock, to cast *find steed* or *find greater steed*, and thus still having access to *Tenser's transformation* via wizard levels. Of course, none of this resolves the problem that it doesn't help with your familiar via *find familiar*...</sub>

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the answers already presented:

## *Glyph of warding* will allow this

The [*glyph of warding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) spell has an option that allows you to store a spell within it to be triggered at a later time. The section on creating a spell glyph reads (emphasis mine):

> You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph. The spell must target a single creature or an area. The spell being stored has no immediate effect when cast in this way. When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast. **If the spell has a target, it targets the creature that triggered the glyph**. If the spell affects an area, the area is centered on that creature. If the spell summons hostile creatures or creates harmful objects or traps, they appear as close as possible to the intruder and attack it. If the spell requires concentration, it lasts until the end of its full duration.
>
> ...When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 4th level or higher...you can store any spell of up to the same level as the slot you use for the *glyph of warding*.

Self-target spells [meet all the requirements](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/115546/63795) to be stored in a *glyph of warding*, and the familiar could trigger the effect. *Glyph of warding* would need to be cast with a spell slot of 6th-level or higher in order to store [*tenser's transformation*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tensers-transformation) in it. When the familiar triggers the glyph it will be the target of the *tenser's transformation* spell which will last the full 10 minutes without requiring concentration.

### Limitations

- *Glyph of warding* has a material cost of 200gp worth of powdered diamond, which the spell consumes. Materials need to be available and it can become quite expensive if you plan to employ this strategy regularly.
- This requires expending two spell slots of 6th-level or higher. The earliest you would be able to accomplish this is Wizard level 13 (plus 3 levels in Warlock if you want your familiar to be able to attack. Familiars do not get access to the Attack action), but you would need to take a long rest after creating the glyph to cast the spell on yourself as well. Wizard level 15 to accomplish this without a long rest.
- Glyphs cannot travel more than 10 feet from the location the spell is cast. [There are ways around this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113708/can-a-portable-hole-be-used-to-get-around-the-10-movement-restriction-on-glyph), but they are largely DM dependant.

Comment: You *could* create a scroll for one of the spells, so you wouldn't need 2 6th-level slots on the same day.  If you're already spending 200g for material components for the glyph in this hypothetical exercise, some time and more gold are also possible to lower the level requirement.

Comment: [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174707/does-a-spell-cast-from-a-glyph-of-warding-with-a-range-of-self-have-infinite-eff) also seems to add range to the glyph spell.  And is very  he-man...

Answer (score 4):

#### This answer falls under the category of "other" mentioned in the question title.

Without a doubt, there are countless better uses for the [Ring of Three Wishes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-three-wishes):

> While wearing this ring, you can use an action to expend 1 of its 3 charges to cast the [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell from it.

Based on the answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107328/can-a-familiar-attune-and-wear-or-use-a-magic-item), your familiar is perfectly capable of using the Ring of Three Wishes to cast *wish*. Your familiar could cast *wish* in order to cast *Tenser's transformation*.

But you should probably think of something better to do with your wishes.